# Transformación XSLT

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

Estoy intentando realizar una transformación XSLT con XPath. Para ello cuento con el siguiente archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<notas>
   <alumno convocatoria="Septiembre">
      <nombre>Carlos</nombre>
      <apellidos>Amaya Arozamena</apellidos>
      <matricula>m019843</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>8.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>8.0</tareas>
      <examen>6.0</examen>
      <final>8.0</final>
   </alumno>
   <alumno convocatoria="Junio">
      <nombre>Jose</nombre>
      <apellidos>Muñoz Soto</apellidos>
      <matricula>m019872</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>7.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>9.0</tareas>
      <examen>7.0</examen>
      <final>8.5</final>
   </alumno>
   <alumno convocatoria="Junio">
      <nombre>Ana</nombre>
      <apellidos>Martinez de la Fuente</apellidos>
      <matricula>m097215</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>8.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>9.0</tareas>
      <examen>9.0</examen>
      <final>8.5</final>
   </alumno>
   <alumno convocatoria="Septiembre">
      <nombre>Roberto</nombre>
      <apellidos>Carrera Fernández</apellidos>
      <matricula>m059312</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>6.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>7.0</tareas>
      <examen>6.0</examen>
      <final>6.5</final>
   </alumno>
   <alumno convocatoria="Septiembre">
      <nombre>Concepción</nombre>
      <apellidos>Lalinde Priego</apellidos>
      <matricula>m034093</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>4.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>3.0</tareas>
      <examen>2.0</examen>
      <final>3.0</final>
   </alumno>
   <alumno convocatoria="Junio">
      <nombre>Esther</nombre>
      <apellidos>Pereda</apellidos>
      <matricula>m938762</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>2.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>3.0</tareas>
      <examen>2.0</examen>
      <final>2.5</final>
      </alumno>
</notas>
```

Con él, necesito filtrar a través de una tabla, los datos de alumnos correspondientes a la convocatoria de Junio. Para ello he generado el siguiente XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:template select="notas"/></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>NOTAS</h1>
                <h2>CONVOCATORIA DE JUNIO</h2>
                <h3>Alumnos</h3>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="notas/alumno"/>             
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//alumno[@convocatoria='Junio']">
        <p>
            <table border="1">
                <td><b>Nombre</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="nombre"/></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Apellidos</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="apellidos"/></p>
                </td>
                <td><b>Tareas</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="tareas"/></p>
                </td>
                <td><b>Cuestionarios</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="cuestionarios"/></p>
                </td>
                <td><b>Nota Final</b>
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="final">
                    <xsl:choose> 
                        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final>=9">Sobresaliente</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final>=8">Notable</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final>=6">Bien</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final>=5">Suficiente</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise test="notas/alumno/final>=0">Insuficiente</xsl:otherwise>  
                    </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:value-of>
                </p>
                </td>
            </table>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

El caso es que no consigo hacer la transformación correctamente y no sé porqué, estoy un poco perdido la verdad. A ver si me podéis orientar un poco.

En un primer momento lo hice con NetBeans y funcionaba, pero necesito hacerlo con otra herramienta. Igualmente, lo que me interesa es corregir el código.

Gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: Cual es la otra herramienta?? Generalmente lo que esta hecho en netbeans o eclipse no termina de generarse adecuadamente, lo infalible es `XMLSpy` y `Stylevision` ambos de `Altova`. Que error te sale?? o que te sale mal??

Comment: La otra herramienta es el XML Copy Editor, y el error que me dice  "Imposible transformar: cannot parse stylesheet".

Comment: Te sugiero que bajes `Stylevision` de altova. En el panel izquierdo donde dice `Vista general de diseño` dice `XML de trabajo`, ahi abre tu XML y te apareceran los nodos abajo en `Estructura del esquema` Cuando lo tengas selecciona un nodo y arrastralo y sueltalo enmedio del documeto cuando estes en la pestaña `diseño` seleccionada. Con el menu `insertar tablas` puedes crear tablas para acomodar todo como si fuera html. Y sigue seleccionando nodos de `Estructura del esquema` y arrastrandolos al documento. En las pestañas `html` y `pdf` puedes ver los resultados.

Comment: Por ultimo Archivo->Guardar archivos generados-> XSLT-HTML y tendrás tu código.

Comment: Con `XMLSpy` tambien de altova puedes debuguear una transformación XSL basandote en un archivo XSLT y en un XML. Tienes un mes con las licencias de prueba que están basadas en un correo electronico.

Comment: Hola Muchas gracias! estoy enreando un poco con XMLSpy, con el XML y el XSL, pero me sale un error respecto al <xsl:value-of select="final"> del XSL, el error dice: que si un elemento <xsl:value-of> tiene un atributo "select" entonces debe tener contenido vacío, y no sé como solucionarlo. Además, consigo que los alumnos con convocatoria de junio aparezcan dentro de una "tabla" pero también aparecen fuera de ella los datos del resto, y eso quiero evitarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque el `xsl:value-of` no se usa para un `xsl:choose`. Ademas el `xsl:otherwise` no lleva condiciones, es un default cuando todas las condiciones no se cumplen. Prueba esto:

```
<td><b>Nota Final</b>
<p>
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final&gt;=&apos;9&apos;"><xsl:text>Sobresaliente</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final&gt;=&apos;8&apos;"><xsl:text>Notable</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final&gt;=&apos;6&apos;"><xsl:text>Bien</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="notas/alumno/final&gt;=&apos;5&apos;"><xsl:text>Suficiente</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>Insuficiente</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>  
    </xsl:choose>
</p>
</td>
```